# Delegate methods are not calling when using seperate thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, delegates

I am using following code for sync phone database with  web database. But -`connectionDidFinishLoading:` method not calling. If I used as `dispatch_sync` instead dispatch_async it works. But I wanted to run this in background thread.

```
 _serialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.company.myApp.SerialQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT);


   __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
   dispatch_async(  _serialQueue, ^{
         [weakSelf sendUnsyncedTickets];
   });

   dispatch_async(  _serialQueue, ^{
         [weakSelf getUnsyncTicketsFromServer];
   });


 -(void)sendUnsyncedTickets{

   serviceConnector = [[ServiceConnector alloc] init];
   serviceConnector.delegate = self;
   [serviceConnector postTest];
   dataMethod = @"send";
   serviceConnector = nil;

 }

  -(void)getUnsyncTicketsFromServer{

    serviceConnector = [[ServiceConnector alloc] init];
    serviceConnector.delegate = self;
    [serviceConnector getTicketsFromServer];
    dataMethod = @"get";

    serviceConnector = nil;

 }
```

--- ServiceConnector.m

```
-(void)getTicketsFromServer{

receivedData = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity: 0];

dataMethod = @"get";


NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/not-redeem.json"]];


[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request addValue:@"getValues" forHTTPHeaderField:@"METHOD"]; 
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

   if(!connection){
       NSLog(@"Connection Failed");
       receivedData = nil;
    }

}


-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{

}
```

Comment: What is the lifetime of the object that is performing the dispatch_async?  Has it been deallocated by the time the action completes?  Have you tried using `self` instead of `_weakself`?

Comment: I don't have time to test right now, but I have seen similar behaviour if the queue isn't backed by, eg, a `NSOperationQueue` such that it will be in existence at the time of the callback.

Comment: `NSURLConnection` must be used from a thread with a runloop.  Simple GCD queues don't meet that criteria.  One way to fix the problem will be to use an `NSOperationQueue` instead.  Another way would be to chain the requests from the completion blocks.

Comment: I have tried with self instead of weakSelf, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @david could you help me to do this with NSOperationQueue or completion blocks.

Comment: see this u will get some idea http://cocoaintheshell.com/2011/04/nsurlconnection-synchronous-asynchronous/